# How to count the number of times a while loop is executed

Tags: c, while-loop

In C, how do you count the number of times a `while` loop is executed?

In Python, I'd just create an empty list in the beginning and append the values from the `while` loop every time the loop is executed. I'd then find the length of that list to know how many times that `while` loop was executed. Is there a similar method in C?

Comment: If your goal was just to count the number of times the loop ran, that’s not exactly the best way to do so in Python either.

Comment: If you'd use that technique in C, your list would need all available memory within a second.

Comment: What are you figuring? maybe `gprof` programa may help you?

Answer (score 13):

Initialise a variable to 0, and increment it on every iteration?

```
int num = 0;

while (something) {
    num++;

    ...
}

printf("number of iterations: %d\n", num);
```

Comment: To by overly clear for the OP's benefit, this is the way you'd do it in Python as well, given the OP's description. I think we're missing a part of the problem, though.

Answer (score 2):

initiate `i = 0` and then `i++` on every loop pass...

Answer (score 2):

(Sorry, this is the C++ way, not C...) If you really want to go for the filling list, this is how it could be done:

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

...

   list<int> my_list;
   int num = 0; 
   while( ... ) {
      ...
      ++num;
      my_list.push_back(num);
   }
   cout << "List size: " << my_list.size() << endl;
```

If you want to print the list values:

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

...

   list<int> my_list;
   int num = 0; 
   while( ... ) {
      ...
      ++num;
      my_list.push_back(num);
   }
   cout << "List contens: " << endl;
   // this line actually copies the list contents to the standard output
   copy( my_list.begin(), my_list.end(), iostream_iterator<int>(cout, ",") );
```

Comment: +1 for the effort, -1 for answering a C question using entirely C++